# How can i block script injection in textbox or textarea using jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a form that contains textbox and textarea. I want to validate it to stop injection of script using textbox or textarea. I need to do it using jquery or javascript.

Is there any RegEx available for that or any other way to detect and stop script.

Comment: The first thing that you should think about is how to validate this on the server. Because no matter what validations you put on the client using javascript any user can simply disable his javascript or craft an HTTP request and send whatever input he likes to the server. Once you have ensured that proper validation is performed on the server you could think about some javascript validation to avoid wasting bandwidth and improving the user experience. Remember that client side validation is not really validation.

Comment: You can use HttpUtility.HtmlEncode as mentioned in [this SO thread][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281746/javascript-injection-attack-prevention-for-textboxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Take a look at ReForm by OWASP:](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_Encoding_Project):

Reform is a tool that does exactly this. Reform allows you to escape your data for a javascript, xml, html or vbscript (yes it still exists) context. It provides libraries for Java, .NET, PHP, Perl, Python, Javascript and ASP.

Secondly, you MUST validate on server-side level as well. JavaScript can easily be disabled in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just saving it in a database, you don't need to do anything. If you're printing out the value in an HTML page, HTML-encode it first. No validation necessary.